# gzip -d returns 'not in gzip format' for file written with BufferedWriter(GZIPOutputStream)

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu, gzip, bufferedwriter

Here my situation:

Code (scala, in an akka.actor):

```
case WriterStart(fileName,actor) =>
{
  this.filename = fileName
  this.actor = actor
  zip = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName)))
  writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zip, "UTF-8"))
  counter = 0
}
case InsertJoinedSubject(model) => //model: StringBuilder
{
  counter += model.lines.size
  writer.append(model)
}
case Finalize() =>
{
  System.out.println("output file " + filename + " has " + counter + " lines")
  writer.flush()
  writer.close()
  context.parent ! WriterClosed(actor, filename)
}
```

This produces a gzip file all right, and can be processed afterwards in my java/scala framework. It also gives no problem when opening it with 7zip under Windows7. 7zip also states it is in gzip format..., but when trying to open a file produced by this writer in an Ubuntu environment with gzip -d (gunzip) it just tells me, that it's 'not in gzip format'.

Comment: @KashyapKansara There is nothing wrong with that. and `OutputStreamWriter` converts one to the other.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : was about to say that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html

Comment: Have you verified with a hex dump that the file on Ubuntu is identical to the same file that could be processed by Java or 7zip?